# Initialized String inside if else become null

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to initialize String inside If else loop, but when I try to display the string value it shows null value.

```
String FavList ;
if(NotificationArr.size()!=0){
    FavList = "true";
    .
    .
    .
 }else{
    FavList = "false";
 }
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "  "+FavList , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: If you cover all cases, the string should contain some value and it shouldn't show `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this condition is never met:

```
if(NotificationArr.size()!=0){
```

then this statement is going to fail..

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "  "+FavList , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

why? 
because the `FavList` is not even initialized...
your IDE can be "smart snough" to prevent that, that is the reason why it is complaining...

so you need to garanty that no matter what
FavList has an initial value

Doing something like this:

```
String FavList = "";
```

would be more than ok in your case...

Comment: Imagine it is met,but then also it shows null value